# How to auto upload image from external source(computer) to webpage

Tags: ftp

I am new to wordpress and I have been looking for a way to get things done with the above subject.

I have successfully found a way to upload images every 10 second from my computer to the /wpuploads folder through FTP and batch process.

Also I have found a way to auto refresh the page so that the image changes every time the page is refreshed.

Now the problem is that I dont want the whole page to be refreshed and I want only the image to refresh. Since the image is not in media content of wordpress thus I am not able to use plugins to do that. Can you suggest me the possible ways to do that.

Comment: I guess you just need to edit the image tag on the page, e.g. remove and re-add it, or maybe even just change the URL, whenever you get a notification that the uploaded image has changed. How are you doing that - websockets?

Comment: But I'm not sure why it matters whether the image is in WordPress's media content or not. How would you do this if it was media content?

Comment: Hey Rup. Thanks for your reply. Actually I have called the image from html tag in elementor. And I am looking for some html code to refresh that image every 10 seconds.